# java storing values from if statement into an array

Tags: java, arrays, variables, if-statement, static-methods

I am having trouble storing values into an array from an `if` statement. For example, I am trying to store values of x and y that make x squared + y squared less than or equal to 1 into an array. These are all done in static methods, and then I want to call them into my main method. Below is my code:

static methods:

```
// simulation of x values static method
public static int xValues(int choice){

    int x = (int) Math.random();

    return x;
}

// simulation of y values static method
public static int yValues(int choice){

    int y = (int) Math.random();

    return y;
}

//////////////// create allowed values for calculation static method
public static int allowedValues(int x, int y){

    if((Math.pow(x, 2) + Math.pow(y, 2)) <= 1){

        /////////// store in an array
    }
}
```

main method:

```
// main method
public static void main(String args[]){

    // create Scanner object
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // call to promptUser
    promptUser();

    // create variable for recieving user input
    int choice = in.nextInt();

    // for loop
    for(int i = 0; i <= choice; i++){

        // call to xValues
        xValues(choice);

        // call to yValues
        yValues(choice);



        // increment i
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exact is your question? What do you try to achieve? Do you get any exceptions? Please post more details ...

Comment: Why are you passing choice to those methods? You are not using them in those methods.

Comment: Suppose that `main` was to be the scope where the array is defined.  Then in your `allowedValues` function, simply return a `1` or `0` (true or false) to determine if you should store `x` and `y` in the array.  Note that you have not captured the return value of either `xValues(choice)` or `yValues(choice)` so you need variables for those as well...

Comment: By the way, tip: when you do `(int)Math.random()` the only number you will get is 0.